# can't see sandbox test account 'Profile' on some computers

Tags: paypal-sandbox

When logged in to developer.paypal.com I can see my test accounts, and enter the sandbox and see notifications, but when I click on 'Profile' my browser turns grey and nothing else happens.

This happens on both of my desktop computers, but oddly, it does not happen on my laptop. On that machine the browser turns grey and then an insert appears with 'Profile', 'API Credentials', 'Funding', and 'Settings' tabs.

What could be blocking the Profile insert on my desktop computers?  Browser (Internet Explorer) third party cookie settings look the same on both machines.

This does not seem to be an issue with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with developer.paypal.com that PayPal is working to resolve. Some users have been able to resolve the issue by clearing cache and cookies.

Note: For IE8 – deleting cookies doesn't delete permanent cookies and requires that you manually delete cookies stored in file system.

A fix is scheduled for 3/19 to address this issue. I will be sure to follow-up on this answer as soon as the issue is resolved.

Thanks!

Comment: I have verified that this issue is now resolved. Please let me know if you run into any issues. Thanks!