# Can't Access Profile Page

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Good afternoon, I am having trouble accessing any of the left-menu items in the Sandbox. I am able to login.

I see the same issue in every browser I have (Chrome, FFX, Safari, IE9) and I have attempted to login using an incognito session. As best I can tell, the error is that the browser never receives a response to an AJAX request to https://www.beta-sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-display-handler&tab_id=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS&&view_requested=MiniPage&_=1367858742397.

I notice this thread, [can't see sandbox test account 'Profile' on some computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406524/cant-see-sandbox-test-account-profile-on-some-computers), indicates a fix on 3/19 and it's 5/6.

I have seen a few workarounds for direct URLs, however, I am unable to figure out what the direct URL to edit the IPN settings would be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that we are working to resolve. I will be sure to follow-up as soon as this issue is fully resolved. In the meantime, you should be able to access your IPN settings using the following link:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify

Thanks,